# pandas groupby apply does not broadcast into a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Using pandas 0.19.0. The following code will reproduce the problem:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'c1' : list('AAABBBCCC'),
                           'c2' : list('abcdefghi'),
                           'c3' : np.random.randn(9),
                           'c4' : np.arange(9)})
        df
Out[2]:     c1  c2  c3          c4
        0   A   a   0.819618    0
        1   A   b   1.764327    1
        2   A   c   -0.539010   2
        3   B   d   1.430614    3
        4   B   e   -1.711859   4
        5   B   f   1.002522    5
        6   C   g   2.257341    6
        7   C   h   1.338807    7
        8   C   i   -0.458534   8

In [3]: def myfun(s):
            """Function does practically nothing"""
            req = s.values
            return pd.Series({'mean' : np.mean(req),
                              'std'  : np.std(req),
                              'foo'  : 'bar'})

In [4]: res = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].apply(myfun)
        res.head(10)
Out[4]: c1  c2      
        A   a   foo          bar
                mean    0.819618
                std            0
            b   foo          bar
                mean     1.76433
                std            0
            c   foo          bar
                mean    -0.53901
                std            0
        B   d   foo          bar
```

And, of course I expect this:

```
Out[4]:         foo  mean      std
        c1  c2     
        A   a   bar  0.819618  0
            b   bar  1.76433   0
            c   bar  -0.53901  0
        B   d   bar  1.43061   0
```

Pandas automatically converts a Series to a DataFrame when returned by a function that is applied to a Series or a DataFrame. Why is the behavior different for functions applied to groups?

I am looking for an answer that will result in the output desired. Bonus points for explaining the difference in behavior among [`pandas.Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

Comment: What you're trying though is fundamentally different, you're returning a Series and the 'columns' you're defining in the dict will become the index, as these index values don't exist it creates them as a new index level. If you did this: `res = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'mean' : [np.mean(x)],
                              'std'  : [np.std(x)],
                              'foo'  : 'bar'}))` then it would work as desired

Comment: @EdChum Thanks Ed. I get it now. I was too sleepy to see it myself.

Comment: Actually, @EdChum I tried returning a DataFrame created with the same dictionary. That didn't work either. That's what threw me off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy fix would be to `unstack`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1' : list('AAABBBCCC'),
                   'c2' : list('abcdefghi'),
                   'c3' : np.random.randn(9),
                   'c4' : np.arange(9)})

def myfun(s):
    """Function does practically nothing"""
    req = s.values
    return pd.Series({'mean' : np.mean(req),
                      'std'  : np.std(req),
                      'foo'  : 'bar'})

res = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].apply(myfun)
res.unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! The index is integrated! It is an index level, obviously. I need more sleep than 4 hours a night. Thanks piRSquared, appreciated.